# Rewriting URL from www.domain.com/folder to folder.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

My web site is made of a root directory which contains index.html + several folders with multiple files.

I want to have URL rewritten such as:

```
http://example.net is rewritten to http://www.example.net
```

(and it displays the file index.html of my root folder)

```
http://www.example.net/folder/file.html is rewritten to http://folder.example.net/file.html
```

(and it displays the file "file.html" of my "folder" directory)

(and of course it works for all my folders and all the files included in these folders!)

Thank you,
Chris.

Comment: Of course I found the answer to the first item of my question :-)
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
But I did not manage to have the second part working, nor having the 2 rules working at the same time (of course!).

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do both. However, all my internal links do not work (links to other pages, images location, css file location).

Here is the htaccess:

```
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).example.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !%1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

My site is structured as:

```
/          <-- only index.html (and .htaccess ;-)
/images/   <-- where all images are stored
/css/      <-- where all css are stored
/folder1/  <-- folder which files can be accessed as folder1.example.net/file.html
/folder2/  <-- folder which files can be accessed as folder2.example.net/file.html
```

In my file.html file, located in /folder1/ directory, css file is referred as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "../css/main.css" title="Normal" />
```

same with my images which are inserted with:

```
<img src = "../images/mylovelyimage.png" alt = "A beautiful picture" />
```

and one link are referred as:

```
<a href = "../folder1/file2.html" title = "second page">Link</a>
```

It appears that css is not loaded, pictures are not displayed, and the link points to http://**folder1**.example.net/**folder1**/file2.html (instead of http://folder1.example.net/file2.html)

Can this be corrected in .htaccess file?